# Override user keys with pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, keypress, pynput

I'm trying to write a program using the pynput library that tracks user key press and when a user presses a special character key like: # my program will press another key right after.
For example, when the user presses the $ sign, The program will press the left key right after and the cursor will move one character behind the $ sign. My problem is that for typing the $ sign the user presses SHIFT + 5 and in most cases the user release only the number key and the shift key stays pressed. In this case when my program presses the left key, insert of pressing only the left key, the SHIFT + left key is pressed, which causes marking the character instead of moving left.
I would like to know if it is possible to ignore the user key or override it in some way.
Appreciate your assistance.
Thanks

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
import re

keyboard = Controller()
REGEX = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key != Key.left:
            if REGEX.search(key.char) != None:
                keyboard.press(Key.left)
                keyboard.release(Key.left)
                print("I pressed left for you")
        else:
            print("Nothing")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could release the `Shift`,them do what you want.
Just in case,if user want to continue press special character,also press the `shift` after you did you work.

So your code could be:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
import re

keyboard = Controller()
REGEX = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key != Key.left:
            if REGEX.search(key.char) != None:
                keyboard.release(Key.shift) # release
                keyboard.press(Key.left) # your work
                keyboard.release(Key.left)
                keyboard.press(Key.shift) # also keep pressed
                print("I pressed left for you")
        else:
            print("Nothing")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it looks like "keyboard.release(Key.shift)" doesn't release the shift pressed by user. Are you using a MAC? may be there is a differences in behavior.

Comment: The shift will stay pressed but the user can still leave the shift pressed so this will not work.